# How to version iterations of a pdf file and read this value using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, version-control

I would like to know which version (iteration) of a Manual.pdf is currently being used. I was hoping to use the file version as reading this is fairly simple in C#. However, it seems like there is no way to set this attribute for a pdf file.

`System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path)`

I could use the last time the file was modified, but this is not ideal. It would be harder to track which version is on the computer.

My second thought was to add a custom property to the pdf document. However, it's not clear how to read this using C#.

I am looking for a lightweight solution. I keep finding advertisements for software that modifies a pdf, but I do not need this ability.

Comment: store version as part of filename ... there is no "lightweight solution" to read pdf without 3rd party library

Comment: _"I am looking for a lightweight solution."_ - there is no "lightweight" when it comes to PDF. PDF has intrinsic versioning, but would require you to at least partially parse its contents (where "you" is "you using a pdf library"). And always remeber: "A PDF is not a PDF is not a PDF". Does this need to work for a specific PDF format or all of them? In that light, Selvin's suggestion to encode it in the file name seems magnitudes simpler.

Comment: We are using Adobe

Comment: Yeah. First mistake. :D Just kidding. Sure you are using Adobe. Which can mean hell of a lot things. You are using it for what and which of their products (other than PDF files)?

Comment: You can use custom metadata to store your version information in the document information dictionary but you will need a PDF library to read it.